# Activities/Application Button doesn't show thumbnails of applications when I search - Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome-shell, search, appmenu, activities-overview

When I open the application menu, thumbnails appear, but when I search for a specific application, it doesn't show.

But it is there, because if I enter, the searched application opens.

All Applications:
[image: All Applications]

When I search for Firefox:
[image: When I search for Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was in a Theme called High_Ubunterra.

To solve it, just execute:

```
sudo apt install yaru-theme-gnome-shell --reinstall
```

It was replacing a default Theme CSS file.

Comment: To mark the question as "solved", please ["accept" the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future. Don't add the word "SOLVED" to the body of the answer.